# Caching is messing up my Live-Stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, streaming

I am trying to stream in my rails app with SSE.

This code works, it is streaming to my browser, BUT the `count` seems to be chached, because when I change it by console, it keeps the same in this controller.

```
class SseController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def stream
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    sse = SSE.new(response.stream)
    begin
      loop do
        count = Email.where(:read => false, :folder_id => nil, :deleted => false, :outgoing => false, :spam => false).count
        sse.write(count, :event => 'refresh')
        sleep 10
      end
      rescue 
      ensure
        sse.close
      end
    end
  end
```

When I do this part in the console. It works as expected.

```
loop do
  count = Email.where(:read => false, :folder_id => nil, :deleted => false, :outgoing => false, :spam => false).count
   sse.write(count, :event => 'refresh')
   sleep 10
end
```

How can I deaktivate chaching or read correct count in my SseController (::Live)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found it:

just needed to do this:

```
Email.uncached do 
  count = ...
end
```